# Doubt about 3D generalization of the Elastic Field Equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, field-theory, elasticity

My only source is $[1]$. In $[1]$ Finn introduces an example (in a totally undergraduate level discussion) that the problem on waves propagating in a solid cylindrical bar, firstly induces you to explore more about the physical conditions concerning the perturbation of an elastic media.

In this problem he presented the so called *Elastic Field Equations* given by:

$$ \begin{cases} \displaystyle F^{x} = YA \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \\ \\ \displaystyle\frac{\partial F^{x}}{\partial x} = \rho A \frac{\partial^{2}\xi}{\partial t^{2}}  \end{cases} \tag{1} $$

Where $F^{x}$ is the one dimensional force called *tension* given by:

> $$ \vec{\mathfrak{S}}A = \vec{F} \iff \vec{\mathfrak{S}} = \frac{1}{A}\vec{F} $$
>
> where $\vec{\mathfrak{S}}$ is the normal tension and $A$ is the area of the surface.

$Y$ is the *Young's Number*, $\rho$ is the density of the material that constitute the bar*, and $\xi$ is the *displacement field of each section of the bar* (which is a scalar field $\xi \equiv \xi(x,y,z,t)$ -that plays the role of a "wave function"-).

Now, I want to rewrite equations $(1)$ in 3D. My try is the following equations:

$$ \begin{cases} \displaystyle \vec{F} = YA \vec{\nabla}\xi \\ \\ \displaystyle \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{F} = \rho A \frac{\partial^{2}\xi}{\partial t^{2}}  \end{cases} \tag{2} $$

My motivation for $(2)$ is then:

**1)** Since  $F^{x} = YA \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}$ then is a equation of components of vector fields.

**2)** Since $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F^{x}}{\partial x} = \rho A \frac{\partial^{2}\xi}{\partial t^{2}}$ then the term $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F^{x}}{\partial x}$ is one of the terms of a divergent operator.

So, are the $(2)$ the correct generalization to $(1)$?

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ FINN E.J, *Fundamental University Physics*, v.2, 2ed, 1983.

Comment: The development is  much more complicated than than that, involving the kinematics of the 3D strains and the stress tensor.  Google something like "Hooke's law derivation in 3D."

Comment: I was awaiting a commentary like that though. But these equations describes nothing at all then?

Comment: Yes, they are inappropriate to use.  You can find the correct equations online, and in any book of Strength or Materials or Theory of Elasticity.